# On a hover event, change the content with data from the parent element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want the hover pseudo element to set the child's content with data from the parent (the hover). The following snippet shows a small test:

CSS

```
.word:hover {
    color: blue;
}
.word:hover ~ #lookup:after {
    content : attr(data-test);
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="word" data-test="elke dag / 每天">everyday</span>
<span class="word" data-test="Ik / 我">I</span>
<span class="word" data-test="drink / 喝">drink</span>
<span class="word" data-test="koffie / 咖啡">coffee</span>
<div id="lookup" data-test="Duh!">Lookup: </div>
```

However, the content that gets set is data-test from the target 'Duh!' instead of the one being hovered over. I can solve this easily with JavaScript, but looking if it is possible using CSS only.

http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/1951/

Comment: Please, do not provide solutions done in JavaScript as this is easy. The question is if this can be done only using CSS. The use-case itself deals with the ruby-tag and can therefore also not use hiding and showing spans.

Comment: In short the answer to your question is no, this can't be done with CSS. I provided a simple alternative in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the mozilla docs, no: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

> The attr() CSS expression is used to retrieve the value of an attribute of the selected element and use it in the style sheet.

Comment: by pointing out that you can't have CSS selector accessing another element - thus, the question posed has the answer "no".

Comment: The question here is, can the previous/parent element's data be selected. I actually came to the same conclusion after reading the MDN earlier today, but was curious if the meaning of 'selected' could be stretched as the CSS expression does mention both elements.

Comment: Thats what I understood to be the case too - it's not like JS where you can mix selectors, the attr() element applies to the current DOM element only.

Comment: If no other answer follows I will accept yours as the correct as the JavaScript answer did at first not explain the motivation to use his solution, although it might be the only way to solve it.

Comment: Good Luck - I'm interested to find out if it's possible also!

Answer (score 1):

My way of solving this would be 
html:

```
<span class="hovertarget">
  <span class="word" >everyday</span>
  <span class="hover">elke dag / 每天</span>
</span>
<span class="hovertarget">
  <span class="word" >I</span>
  <span class="hover">Ik / 我</span>
</span>
<span class="hovertarget">
  <span class="word" >drink</span>
  <span class="hover">drink / 和</span>
</span>
<span class="hovertarget">
  <span class="word" >coffee</span>
  <span class="hover">koffie / 咖啡</span>
</span>
```

css:

```
.hover {
 display:none;
}
.hovertarget:hover .word {
 display: none;
}
.hovertarget:hover .hover {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Does not work in a similar fashion as the content itself gets switched. The original fiddle uses a div in which the lookup information is placed. This also prevents the 'trigger-happy' on hover event in some browsers as it is now even hard to select the word 'coffee' and see the lookup.

Comment: use anchor tags and style it as you please

Comment: Although the example given is simple, the point is to store metadata and this is now in a way lost, as it is not part of the original element as a dataset. Yes, your example works but did not answer the actual question: 'can it be done only using CSS?'.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very clever usage of CSS3 technology, but unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do what you're trying to do with just CSS. The problem is that you can't use `attr()` from a different selector other than the one you're currently in. The workaround is very simple in JavaScript.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var lookup = document.getElementById('lookup'),
        words = document.querySelectorAll('.word');

    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        words[i].mouseover = function() {
            lookup.innerHTML = 'Lookup: '+ this.getAttribute('data-test');
        }
    }
};
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Au68C/)**

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer and adding the "Can't use" as I also believe JavaScript is the only way to solve this.